# Local language not parsing in MS ReportViewer print option

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer

I am developing a windows application form where I am using some local language fonts (Marathi a local Indian language). I am using MS reportviewer control. But whenever I click on print, the local characters are not parsing (they are simply showing as block characters). Can someone please point me in the direction to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, by debugging more I have figure out the issue. While creating by rdlc report I set the font of the text-box (where the result is displaying) as English one. I changed to Arial Unicode MS font and now it is displaying fine. If someone wants to include custom fonts they can also include this. Just right-click on the text-box in your rdlc report and go to Font and set the required font type option.

Thanks